# Gauge Series of Highcharts with React not the Solid Gauge but Gauge Series

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

https://www.highcharts.com/demo/gauge-speedometer

Need this chart in React. Implemented Solid Gauge but was not able to implement this Gauge Series.

Here is the Sandbox for reference where the Solid Gauge is working but not series graph. Uncommenting the GaugeSeries leads to tooltip of null error.

https://codesandbox.io/s/38rk6wvnrq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `plotOptions` should be part of chart options in

```
  <HighchartsChart
    chart=
```

I suggest changing the name of the variable, so it will not be misleading - e.g. to `chartOptions`.

Second, and the most important problem is caused by a typo - series type is `gauge` and not `guage` the:

```
      <Series id="series" name="Value" data={[80]} type="guage" />
```

Based on the code:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Highcharts from "highcharts";
require("highcharts/highcharts-more")(Highcharts);
require("highcharts/modules/exporting")(Highcharts);

import {
  HighchartsChart,
  withHighcharts,
  Series,
  XAxis,
  YAxis,
  Tooltip
} from "react-jsx-highcharts";

const plotOptions = {
  plotBackgroundColor: null,
  plotBackgroundImage: null,
  plotBorderWidth: 0,
  plotShadow: false
};

const paneOptions = {
  startAngle: -120,
  endAngle: 120,
  background: [
    {
      backgroundColor: {
        linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
        stops: [[0, "#FFF"], [1, "#333"]]
      },
      borderWidth: 0,
      outerRadius: "109%"
    },
    {
      backgroundColor: {
        linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
        stops: [[0, "#333"], [1, "#FFF"]]
      },
      borderWidth: 1,
      outerRadius: "107%"
    },
    {
      backgroundColor: "#DDD",
      borderWidth: 0,
      outerRadius: "105%",
      innerRadius: "103%"
    }
  ]
};

const GraphRender = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <div className="gauge-empty">
      <div className="no-data">Data Unavaialble</div>
      <HighchartsChart
        chart={{ type: "gauge" }}
        plotOptions={plotOptions}
        pane={paneOptions}
      >
        <Tooltip padding={10} hideDelay={250} shape="square" />

        <XAxis />

        <YAxis
          id="myAxis"
          min={0}
          max={100}
          minorTickInterval="auto"
          minorTickWidth={1}
          minorTickLength={10}
          minorTickPosition="inside"
          minorTickColor="#666"
          tickPixelInterval={30}
          tickWidth={2}
          tickPosition="inside"
          tickLength={10}
          tickColor="#666"
          labels={{
            step: 2,
            rotation: "auto"
          }}
          title={{
            text: ""
          }}
          plotBands={[
            {
              from: 0,
              to: 60,
              color: "#55BF3B" // green
            },
            {
              from: 60,
              to: 80,
              color: "#DDDF0D" // yellow
            },
            {
              from: 80,
              to: 100,
              color: "#DF5353" // red
            }
          ]}
        >
          <Series id="series" name="Value" data={[80]} type="guage" />
        </YAxis>
      </HighchartsChart>
    </div>
  );
};

const Gauge = ({ data }) => <GraphRender data={data} />;

export default withHighcharts(Gauge, Highcharts);
```

*(I have not resolved the problem with the chart option - you can move the options into the correct place if you want them to work. I'm not sure if you want them or if those were set only for the demo purpose)*

Comment: Thanks, That helped.

Comment: same problem here, link not work anymore. Can't understand from where I need to import <Series component. If it possible, update your link.

Comment: @degr Replaced the broken link with some relevant code. The solution was based on the code in question, so you could use that link to view the chart. In general I would advice usage of [the official Highcharts wrapper for React](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react).